# Проверка статуса файлов

Tags: php, файлы

Доброго времени суток!
Вот у меня задача, нужно проверить за один раз несколько файлов в директории, доступны ли  файлы для записи. Вот так, я проверяю состояние одного файла. Как проверить за один раз несколько файлов, и вывести статус, каждого файла ?

```
<?

$filename = '../file.txt';

if (is_writable ($filename)) {

echo "файл $filename доступен для записи ";
}
else
{
echo "файл $filename недоступен для записи";
}

?>
```

Comment: В цикле тоже самое...

Comment: напишите пожалуйста пример. Я тольконачил изучать php

Comment: попробуй занести адреса файлов в массив и перебором через for() определяй атрибут каждого файла.

Answer (score 1):

Вот код смотрит файлы в каталоге, проходит по ним проверяя что есть файл что каталог, а потом проверяет доступен ли файл для чтения.

```
 <?php
    $dir = "example";
    $files1 = scandir($dir , 1);

    foreach ($files1 as &$value)
    {
    if(is_dir ($value)==false)
    {
    echo "<br><br>Найден файл:" . $value;

    if (is_writable ($value)) {

    echo "<br>файл $value доступен для записи ";
    }
    else
    {
    echo "<br>файл $value недоступен для записи";
    }
    }
    else
    {
    echo "<br><br>Найден каталог:" . $value;
    }
    }

    ?>
```

Comment: Спасибо! код работает.